# Cumulative distribution function and probabilities

Tags: probability-theory

I've run into problem with this exercise:

> Let $X$ have distribution function:
>
> $F(x)=\begin{cases}
> 0,  & \text{if $x$}<0 \\
> \frac{1}{2}x, & \text{if }0\leq x\leq 2,  \\
> 1, & \text{if }x>2, 
> \end{cases}$

I need to find:

> a) $P(x\leq 1)$
>
> b) $P(0.5 \leq x)$

Answers are $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$ respectively. Could anyone explain me how to obtain them? Thanks!

Comment: What is the _definition_ of $F(x)$? Perhaps you could edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Please do not confuse $x$ and $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (cumulative) distribution function $F(x)=F_X(x)$ tells us the probability that $X\le x$. Write this as $\Pr(X\le x)$.

So for (a), we can **read off** the answer directly from the given formula. We want $\Pr(X\le 1)$. This is $F(1)$, which is $\frac{1}{2}$.

For (b), we want $\Pr(X\ge 0.5)$, which is equal to $1-\Pr(X\lt 0.5)$.

But $X$ has a *continuous* distribution, so $\Pr(X\lt 0.5)=\Pr(X\le 0.5)$. This is $F(0.5)$, which is $0.25$.

It follows that $\Pr(X\ge 0.5)=1-0.25=0.75$.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks for help! 

BTW -- shouldn't there be $Pr(X\ge 0.5)=1-0.25=0.75$ instead of $Pr(X\ge 0.5)=1-0.5=0.75$

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for catching the typo.